# Any way to serialize javax.el.LambdaExpression?

Tags: java, serialization, el

According to its constructor, `LambdaExpression` is basically a combination of a `List` of strings and a `ValueExpression`. Both of these components are naturally serializable. However, `LambdaExpression` is not, presumably because of `setElContext()` method, which requires to store a non-serializable object somewhere.

Is there still any way to serialize a lambda expression without involving reflection? Unfortunately, there are no getters for the constructor arguments in the class...

**This question is about EL lambda object as seen from Java, not Java lambda expressions.**

Comment: What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Serialize a lambda expression so that i can later deserialize it. What else?

Comment: You most likely need to use it in a context.  That context may be relevant.